# Getting maximum of an array without a second variable?

Tags: c++

Is there a way I can find the maximum of an array without the use of nested loops / 2nd variable ? maybe or maybe not using swaps too depending on how possible/impossible it is with the first 2 requirements

Cheers!

Also this is a question I tried so hard to think of because I heard it was asked in an interview before but I failed to reach a solution!

EDIT: No function is to be used, and by 2nd variable I meant the "max" variable we usually use, only allowed to use a loop to iterate through the array elements, we can only use the array elements itself though even if we change all their values for the sake of getting the maximum out of it.

Comment: Depending on the parameters of the quiz, you could `std::sort` the array. Sure, there are loops involved, but you didn't write them.

Comment: `auto largest = *std::max_element(std::begin(theArray), std::end(theArray));`

Comment: No no , no functions are involved! its without functions and when I meant without 2nd variable I meant the "max" variable we usually use, my bad didn't clarify well

Comment: What is the practical reason for not using `std::max_element`? There is a function that does exactly what you want. Use it! Don't make things more complicated than they need to be. The next person to read your code will thank you.

Comment: @Kalcor - With the edit you gave in your question, are you sure you were told all of these esoteric details on what you can't use?  I can't believe you would remember such a stupid question with all of these details.

Comment: If an interview question for C++ asks you to do something and forbids the 
 use of the standard library, it's time to leave. I know it's not always that simple for intern and graduate positions, but just yikes...

Comment: I think this should be closed for being way too specific on something that is extremely unlikely to be useful in the future

Comment: I don't think this should be closed, as many people *do* get asked these kinds of questions in interviews - for those who don't get the point:
this is a more logical / mathematical riddle, it's not primarily about programming or using the std library... pretty much like other logical riddles they may give you. Just to see how you react, and how you approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I got this question, in an interview, the interviewer disallowed sorting because it either alters the source array or forces you to sort into a temporary array. He balked at a looping variable (though he didn't object to tracking the size of the array - go figure). He also argued that there are better than O(n log n) solutions. So here's the O(n) solution to this dumb question.

```
#include <algorithm>

int int_max(int * array, int size) {
  if (size == 1)
    return *array;

  return std::max(*array, int_max(array+1, size-1));
}
```

Under no circumstances, whatsoever, should anyone, ever, ever, ever, consider this to be a good idea. **It answers a stupid interview question, and that's about it.** You will blow the stack. Bad things will happen. And, just because I'm not declaring a variable doesn't mean I'm not generating one on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it is a stupid interview question and not practical for real world usage.

Answer (score 4):

You only need one variable, to contain the maximum value.

```
int maximum_value = std::numeric_limits<int>min();
for (size_t i = 0; i < array_capacity; ++i)
{
  if (array[i] > maximum_value)
  {
    maximum_value = array[i];
  }
}
```

See also [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

**Edit 1:  No additional variables, except loop index**

```
for (size_t i = 1U; i < array_capacity; ++i)
{
  if (array[i] > array[0])
  {
    array[0] = array[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Shoot. Forgot `max_element`. That's even better than sorting.

Comment: No no , no functions are involved! its without functions and when I meant without 2nd variable I meant the "max" variable we usually use, my bad didn't clarify well

Comment: The `numeric_limits<int>min` is a compile-time constant.  You can use some value that is guaranteed to be the lowest value.

Comment: See my changes, Edit 1.